# Use regex to check if particular directory has folders starting with specific word

Tags: bash, command-line, regular-expression

I am writing a script that checks a certain directory for any sub-directories starting with a specific word.

Here is my script thus far:

```
#!/bin/bash

function checkDirectory() {
    themeDirectory="/usr/share/themes"
    iconDirectory="/usr/share/icons"
    # I don't know what to put for the regex. 
    regex=

    if [ -d "$themeDirectory/$regex" && -d "$iconDirectory/$regex" ]; then
       echo "Directories exist."
    else
       echo "Directories don't exist."
    fi
}
```

So, how would you use `regex` to check if a particular directory has any folders starting with a specific word?

Comment: regular expressions are more powerful than "starting with a specific word". Is there a reason you *need* regex?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I don't know, I just thought since I know the directory will have directories starting with a specific word, I thought that would be the best solution. For example, in the theme directory, I know 'Numix' is the starting word to each of the sub-directories (that is if the 'Numix' theme is installed) located inside the theme directory, thus I thought if I use regex I could locate all those files inside that directory and check if they exist or not.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the test expression you've written, since you seem to be checking if directories with the given name prefix exist in _both_ of your target directories

Comment: Related: https://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/223634

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to find directories matching a given pattern/prefix, I think you could just use `find`:

```
find /target/directory -type d -name "prefix*"
```

or, if you only want *immediate* subdirectories:

```
find /target/directory -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "prefix*"
```

Of course, there's also `-regex`if you need an actual regex match. (caveat: I can't remember if -maxdepth is a gnu-ism.)

(update) Right, you wanted an if statement. Find always returns a zero, so we can't use the return value to check if anything was found (unlike with grep). But we can e.g. count the lines. Pipe the output through `wc` to get the count, then see if it's not zero:

```
if [ $(find /target/directory -type d -name "prefix*" | wc -l ) != "0" ] ; then
    echo something was found
else
    echo nope, didn't find anything
fi
```

Comment: So if I wanted to check this using an if-else structure, just surround the  `find /target/directory -type d -name "prefix*"` in an if statement like: `if [ find /target/directory -type d -name "prefix*" ]; then ... else .... fi`?

Comment: @NicholasAdamou, yah, I updated the answer with one way to do that (of course there are others)

Comment: `-maxdepth` and `-regex` are gnu-isms but are now found in some other `find` implementations (with variations for `-regex`). Here, you probably want `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` or with FreeBSD `find`: `-depth 1`. Or POSIXly `find dir/. ! -name . -prune ...`

Comment: I'd do `if find /target/directory -type d -name "prefix*" | grep -q '^'; then...` to stop as soon as possible (or use `-print -quit` with GNU/FreeBSD...).

Answer (score 2):

`-d` doesn't accept regexes, it accepts filenames. If you just want to check a simple prefix, a wildcard is enough:

```
exists=0
shopt -s nullglob
for file in "$themeDirectory"/word* "$iconDirectory"/* ; do
    if [[ -d $file ]] ; then
        exists=1
        break
    fi
done
if ((exists)) ; then
    echo Directory exists.
else
    echo "Directories don't exist."
fi
```

`nullglob` makes the wildcards expand to empty lists if there are no matches. In a larger script, change its value in a subshell, or set back the old value once you don't need it.

Comment: So if I also wanted to check if `$iconDirectory` has any sub directories, I would do `"$iconDirectory"/word*`?

Comment: @NicholasAdamou: It's already there.

Answer (score 1):

The name of your variable `regex` will not be well chosen but consider setting the value to `"$1"` like `regex="$1"`. Next step is to change the `if` statement from:

```
if [ -d "$themeDirectory/$regex" && -d "$iconDirectory/$regex" ]; then
```

to

```
if [ -d "$themeDirectory/$regex" ] && [ -d "$iconDirectory/$regex" ]; then
```

The script will become:

```
function checkDirectory() {
    themeDirectory="/usr/share/themes"
    iconDirectory="/usr/share/icons"
    # I don't know what to put for the regex. 
    regex="$1"

    if [ -d "$themeDirectory/$regex" ] && [ -d "$iconDirectory/$regex" ]; then
       echo "Directories exist."
    else
       echo "Directories don't exist."
    fi
}
```

From a shell you can source your script by:

```
. /path/to/script
```

And the function is ready for use:

```
checkDirectory test
Directories don't exist.
```

Comment: Will this locate any directories inside both the theme directory and the icon directory starting with a specific word?

Comment: Well, 'locate' is a big word, the if statement will check if a directory (`test` in my sample) exist in `$themeDirectory` as well as in `$iconDirectory`. If both directories (`/usr/share/themes/test` and `/usr/share/icons/test`) exists the message `"Directories exist."` is printed, otherwise the message `"Directories don't exist."` is printed.